# Timestamp comparison in MySQL for same months / different years

Tags: mysql

I'm using SQL to query three tables for data analysis. I need to compare timestamps for three months- Jan, Feb, March but over different years.

My code so far for the WHERE clause is:

```
a.time_stamp BETWEEN '%y%/10/01 00:00:00' AND '%y%/01/01 00:00:00'
```

and it is not returning the right result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL lets you select the month from a date:

```
select MONTH(now()); // -> 1 (in January)
```

so you might try (not tested):

```
WHERE MONTH(a.time_stamp) >= 1 and MONTH(a.time_stamp) <=3
```